# How to search for string in one column and return another coumn in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that loads data like:

```
 src_data =  pd.read_csv('source_network.csv')

 Name     Source   Description
 ------------------------------
 ABC      PQR      ABC
 CBD      AAAQ     WER
 ABC      GHI      PFQ
```

I am trying to run a function to search if dataframe column matches a string and return another column if a match is found

Code:

```
 def write_To_yaml(df, model):
       data = df.loc[df['Name'] == model, 'Source']

 src_networks =  pd.read_csv('source_network.csv')
 for model in filenames:

     write_To_yaml(src_networks, model)
```

I get an error saying :

```
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  KeyError: 'Name'
```

I tried another approach:

```
  for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
      if row[0] == model_name:
          print('Match found for:', model_name)
```

But this doesn't give correct results, some of the results are not displayed even if the row matches with model name.

Can someone suggest me the right and optimal way to solve this issue?

Comment: `df.loc[df['Name'] == model, 'Source']` this seems to be correct but you have used wrong dataframe name as `df` instead of `src_networks`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, corrected now

Comment: what does `print (src_data.columns)` give you?

Comment: This is what print(src_networks.columns):Index(['Name ', 'Framework & Type ', 'Input_Tensors ', 'Description ',
       'Source ', 'Paper ', 'Dataset ', 'Modifications '],
      dtype='object')

Comment: So you have white space after the words. after `read_csv` clean your columns header with `src_data.columns = src_data.columns.str.strip()`, then it should work